# How to interpret this regression outcome

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, categorical-data

Hello I hope someone can give me some valuable insight.

Prior to my analysis/regression, I checked the average market shares over a six year time period over different (countries) regions.

Region A: highest share
Region B: 2nd highest share
Region C: 3rd highest share
Region D: 4th highest share
Region E: 5th highest share
Region F: 6th highest share

In my regression I use the regions as dummies, and take Region A with the highest share as base and the shares (dependent variable) are transformed (log).

Now to my understanding I thought that Region B, which is the closest to Region A in terms of shares, would have the smallest negative coefficient and then followed by C, D, E, F. But this is not the case it goes from: B, E, C, F and D. Is my understanding wrong?

*btw: the number of countries in the regions are not equal, example Region D has 4 countries in my analysis and Region F has 11 countries for example.

Comment: I do not get this analysis, or I am missing something. If the six tiers of shares are just a binned (aggregated) version of the continuous share variable, what is the point? You already know the categorization scheme, why bother to test an apparent association? Also, the time variable is not considered in the analysis. Some countries could have existe in the analysis 6 times... That woul not be proper for regression.

Comment: Well I had to put the regions in my regression as control variables and after I got the output, my teacher looked at it and said: and are these results the same as in your figure with the average shares per region over that time period? So I made the assumptions that the results of my regression had to be somewhat similar (or logical) as in the figure.

Comment: So, if other variables are in the regression as well the two-variable association between share and region does not need to hold, because other variables in the model could have confounded the said association, which is to say your situation is not necessarily an anomaly.

Comment: So let $Y_i$ be the "market share" for region $i$. Let $y_i = \log Y_i$. Let $I_{B,i}, I_{C,i}, \ldots,  I_{F,i}$ be dummy variables for regions B through F respectively. You ran the regression $y_i = b_0 + b_B I_{B,i} + b_C I_{C,i}+ b_D I_{D,i}+ b_E I_{E,i}+ b_F I_{F,i}+ \epsilon_i$. Do I understand properly?

Comment: When you say region A has the highest average share, is this based upon an average of market share $\frac{1}{n_A} \sum_{i \in A} Y_i$ or the average of log market share $ \frac{1}{n_A} \sum_{i \in A}  y_i$?

Comment: @Penguin_Knight (love your name btw), yes in total I have six main drivers and 8 (including the regions) control variables. When I run the regression with only the regions I get the same results.

Comment: @MatthewGunn, hi thanks for your reply. Yes thats how I run the regression (but my regression has more variables than just the regions).
and yes with highest average share I mean the average of market share and not the average of log market share.

Comment: So your regression differs from taking the simple, arithmetic average of market share by region in two ways: (1) you're running the regression on the *logarithm* of market share and (2) you're adding some additional control $X$. Either of those two could explain why the ordering changes? If you regress market share $Y_i$ only on your dummies $I_B, \ldots, I_F$ your coefficients should be exactly as you say they are because that regression is estimating the mean market share conditional on region.

Comment: @MatthewGunn you're RIGHT! I regressed market share Y (not the log) only on the region dummies and it makes sense now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y_i$ be the "market share" of country $i$. You're saying that region A has a higher market share than region B etc..., that is: $$ \bar{Y}_A < \bar{Y}_B < \ldots < \bar{Y}_F$$
where $\bar{Y}_R = \frac{1}{n_R} \sum_{i \in R} Y_i$ denotes the mean market share for region $R$.

#### What should follow your logic/intuition:

Let $I_{R,i}$ be a dummy variable for country $i$ being in region $R$.
If you ran the regression:

$$Y_i = b_0 + b_B I_{B, i} + b_C I_{C, i} + b_D I_{D, i} + b_E I_{E, i} + b_F I_{F, i} + \epsilon_i$$
the estimated coefficients would be exactly as you expect. $\hat{b}_0 = \bar{Y}_A$ and $\hat{b}_B = \bar{Y}_B - \bar{Y}_A$.

#### But this is the regression you're running:

$$\log Y_i = b_0 + b_B I_{B, i} + b_C I_{C, i} + b_D I_{D, i} + b_E I_{E, i} + b_F I_{F, i} + \mathbf{x}_i \cdot \mathbf{b} + \epsilon_i$$

So it's no longer the case that estimate $\hat{b}_B$ need be negative etc... for two reasons:

- The logarithm is not a linear function.
- You've added the control variable (or vector) $\mathbf{x}$.